# Android button loses color when placed on a background

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom button (relative layout) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_alege_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_rel_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_button_alege_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_rel_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="buton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_rel_text1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_button_alege_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I place it on a relative layout that has a background with color, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/grad_blue">

        <include android:id="@+id/btn_backmsg"
            layout="@layout/test_buton_white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
...
```

The @drawable/grad_blue is a dark blue gradient. So it is supposed to be a darkblue gradient background with a white button on top of it.

But when I run the app and go to the activity, the button does not have the white color that I set it's layout to. It is colored a little darker than the background of the layout that is stands in.
How can I avoid this?
I mean how can I do it so that the button stay white?

Thank you

Comment: Come on guys, it should be simple. A white button on a colored background...?

Comment: Perhaps `@layout/test_buton_white` versus `@layout/test_button_white` ...

Comment: Try to set fixed width and height to the <include> (as 130x50dp)

Comment: Delpes... seriously... it is just the name I gave to the layout (it does not have to be in English, it just needs to be the same in the activity's layout as it is declared)

Comment: Fllo, even if I do not understand how the size would help solving a color setting problem, I tried your idea and still nothing. Could you perhaps try the code and see for yourself? Thank you

Comment: You can try it with any other background color, not necessarily a gradient. Just put a dark color in the background and you will see what I mean. Thanks again

Comment: I'll try your code asap. I thought the wrap_content value "ate" the content.

Comment: No, the content is there it just has a darker than the background - color

Comment: I tried your code into a new project and I cannot recreate your issue (both with simple color and gradient, [see the screenshots](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wCfGD.jpg)). Could you add your custom background and some screenshots? Maybe I'm missing something.